# ORA-06550: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";"

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

ORA-06550: line 20, column 4:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:

if
1. declare
2. a number;
3. b number;

### 4. c number;

```
declare
a number;
b number;
c number;
d number;

function findMaxOfAll(x in number, y in number, z in number)
return number
is
m number;
begin
  if x > y and x > z then
    m:=x;
     else if y > x and y > z then
       m:=y;
        else
          m:=z;
  end if;
  return m;
end;

begin
a:=34;
b:=76;
c:=56;
d:=findMaxOfAll(a, b, c);
dbms_output.put_line('Max of all is: ' || d);
end;
```

Comment: Haven't done SQL in a while but are you sure that you end an if statement with `end if` or just `end`?

Comment: You have two If statements but only one "end if".  if you add an extra End if in the appropriate place then this will work

Comment: @MotKohn yes i'm sure!

Comment: @ShaunPeterson thanks it works!

Comment: Before you write any code, make sure you solve the problem correctly. Assuming the code is fixed, what do you think it will produce as the MAX if x = 20, y = 20, z = 15? (Answer: it will say the max is 15; can you see why?)

Comment: can you format your post: the error message is unclear if formatted this way, the caption "4.c number" does not make any sense, the indentation of the if blocks in the function is confusing.

Answer (score 3):

The trouble is with the `ELSE IF`.

Change it to `ELSIF`.

```
if x > y and x > z then
    m:=x;
     elsif y > x and y > z then
       m:=y;
        else
          m:=z;
  end if;
```

Answer (score 3):

I donot understand the use of this snippet as oracle already provides GREATEST Function to execute this type of operations.
These are easier to use and optimized.
Hope this helps.

```
SELECT greatest('&x','&y','&z') FROM dual;
```